# Website Blocked in Certain Workplaces as "Harmful"

Tags: google-adsense, keywords

I recently founded a small social site. Until recently, no users complained of being unable to view the site at work.

It's been a few weeks since then, and after adding a bit more text content, was recently approved for Google Adsense. Now a number of my users are unable to log into my site at their work places because my website is considered "harmful", and in some cases, even "pornographic".

There is absolutely no pornographic or harmful content on my site whatsoever, and there never has been. It's a niche social networking site for lonely people, and the only images I have are small generic icons.

The ads that appear are often for dating sites (probably because of the theme of loneliness, but I am not running a dating service or anything of the sort at all), many of them advertising for "hot (x ethnic group) girls".

1) The ads are directly from Google... could they potentially be what is causing the workplace blocking problem?

2) Is there any way I can force Google Adsense to give me more appropriate ads?

3) Is this a just problem with the fact that some of my key words are "lonely" and "chat"?

4) This is affecting a number of workplaces. Is there some sort of certification or whitelist I can be put on?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Log onto Google Adsense, click on Allow & block ads, then Sensitive categories. Turn off Dating. And for that matter almost if not all of the other categories if you do not want this to happen again.

Comment: So you're saying that Google ads could *alone* be what's responsible for my site's bad rep, without any particular content on my site?

Comment: Sometimes. What happens is that blocking software sites scan your website and may confuse text ads and possibly some other type of ads as an indication of what your site is about. Ironically, these filters are not too bright. They do not have to be. This is because the buying public assumes that they are fully developed. But they are not. I had similar issues where sites are categorizing my site as *something* when clearly it is not. For example, because I report abusive domains that have dirty words in the domain name, it is assumed that my site is a porn site. Funny huh? Ads can do this too.